# Не работает RegularExpressionValidator

Tags: c#, asp.net

Есть пустая web-форма, на которой тестируется регулярное выражение

```
<asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txb_text1" MaxLength="15"></asp:TextBox>
    <asp:RegularExpressionValidator runat="server" ID="regular1" ControlToValidate="txb_text1" ErrorMessage="not much"
         ForeColor="Red" ValidationExpression="^([0-9]){15}$"
        ></asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
    <asp:Button Text="button" runat="server" ID="button1"/>
```

Проверка должна быть на числовое значение в 15 цифр (ни больше, ни меньше).
Но в результате пропускает только в случае пустого текстбокса.

Само выражение проверил [здесь](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5E(%5B0-9%5D)%7B15%7D%24&i=012345678901234&o=s)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Сам и нашел. Нужно поставить свойство у RegularExpressionValidator

`EnableClientScript="false"`

чтобы отключить проверку на стороне клиента.